# After a bacterial infection is dealt with, do any of that colony of bacteria remain?

Tags: bacteriology, antibiotics, antibiotic-resistance

Suppose that I get a bacterial infection, which my immune system deals with. Are there any remnant bacteria, or are they all gone? Now consider the same scenario, but having been treated with a full course of antibiotics - are there any bacteria left alive? Now suppose I take a partial course of the antibiotics - enough to reduce the bacterial population to a level that my own immune system can deal with by itself. In this last case, if I beat the infection, is there any chance of bacteria having evolved resistance to those antibiotics, or are they all dead?

I ask having recently read an [article](http://theconversation.com/no-you-dont-have-to-finish-all-your-antibiotics-38774) claiming that conventional wisdom on antibiotics might not be as useful as once thought.

Comment: Have you read anything on resistant bacteria?

Comment: @rg255 yes; what are you getting at?

Comment: I think @rg255 is on the generation of resistance by not finishing antibiotical treatments...

Comment: Which is exactly what I'm interested in, but am questioning the 'accepted' wisdom of the matter.

Comment: Can you point out exactly where the article states "a full dose of antibiotics is somewhat arbitrarily determined and based on a single case study"? (It did state recommended "antibiotic courses are often arbitrary; they may reflect long-standing convention or be based on a manufacturer’s decision during an initial drug trial." Note that an initial drug trial is light years from a single case study. (cont.)

Comment: Furthermore, the paper states that "**Recent clinical trials** show that even for some serious infections, shorter antibiotic courses can be as effective as conventional, longer ones," which directly contradicts your assertion that duration of antibiotic treatment is arbitrarily determined. The article has a lot of correct information, but can be easily misinterpreted, which I believe you have done.

Comment: @anongoodnurse fair call; which is why I'm asking the question here.